# Bash shell script: Count lines in each paragraph in a file based on a field separator?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I want to analyze log file but stuck in this case:

Example:
I have a file with format like this:

```
140508  0:00:19 10 abc  def
            9  djdj djdjd
            12 fjfj fjfjj                       
140508  0:00:24         10 dhdh dhdh
            19 dddh  hdhdhd
            1838 jcjj ddhfhfh
            17 fhfhh fhfhfh
140508  0:00:29         10 ababa cbcbc
```

Field separator is 140508 (YYMMDD).

I want to output the count of lines in each paragraph based on the field separator:

```
140508  0:00:19 3
140508  0:00:24 4
140508  0:00:29 1
```

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like a more proper analysis of the log file format would be the absence of an indent. This is borh easier to parse and easier to generalize so that the solution works for other dates, too.

Answer (score 3):

Using awk:

```
awk '/^[0-9]{6} /{if (c) print a, b, c; a=$1; b=$2; c=1; next} {c++} END{print a, b, c}' file
140508 0:00:19 3
140508 0:00:24 4
140508 0:00:29 1
```

Comment: It seem wrong. I run your script with above example and it show this result: "140508 0:00:29 8"

Comment: I provided output of awk command as well. Is it not same as your expected output?

Comment: Can you explain (c) in your script.
Yes, your result is right but when i run it give me another result.
[root@TESTSRV user]# cat test
140508  0:00:19 10 abc  def
            9  djdj djdjd
            12 fjfj fjfjj
140508  0:00:24         10 dhdh dhdh
            19 dddh  hdhdhd
            1838 jcjj ddhfhfh
            17 fhfhh fhfhfh
140508  0:00:29         10 ababa cbcbc
[root@TESTSRV user]# awk '/[0-9]{6}/{if (c) print $1, $2, c; c=1; next} {c++} END{print $1, $2, c}' test
140508 0:00:29 8

Comment: `c` is just a counter that start with `1` every time it matches a pattern `/[0-9]{6}/`. If you are getting problems then provide a sample input in your question that can reproduce the problem and I will adjust my command accordingly.

Comment: @consoko: Sounds like you're running a version of GNU `akw` < 4 - try adding the `--re-interval` option.

Comment: Your solution doesn't work, as demonstrated by the sample output: you're reporting the _next_ paragraph's time in each output line.

Comment: Thanks for the update; +1. Your solution is even POSIX-compliant. (On GNU `awk` < 4 you have to add `--posix` or `--re-interval` to make it work.) Anchoring the regex and appending a space would help robustness - `/^[0-9]{6} /`.

Comment: Thanks improved my regex as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

using awk

```
awk '/:/{h=$1 FS $2}{a[h]++}END{for (i in a) print i,a[i]}' file
```

#### Explanation

- `/:/{h=$1 FS $2}`, work on line of `:` only, and generate the index of array a.
- `{a[h]++}` sum the times on that index.
- `{for (i in a) print i,a[i]}` go through the array a and do the print job.

Comment: It work for me. Can you explain your script?? Thanks.

Comment: It's concise, but note that due to using `i in a` the order of output lines will not match the input order. Also, matching against `/^[0-9]/` is probably more robust.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `awk`:

```
awk --re-interval -v RS='(^|\n)[0-9]{6} ' \
 '$0=="" {sep=RT; next}  {print sep $1, 1+gsub("\n.",""); sep=substr(RT,2)}'  file
```

Note: If your `gawk` version is >= `4.0`, you don't need the `--re-interval` option.

Explanation:

- The date expression `[0-9]{6}`  is used as the record separator (`RS`), which automatically splits the input into the desired paragraphs; preceding it with `(^|\n)` ensures that matching is only performed at the *beginning* of lines.
- `RT` contains the literal record *terminator* that matched the `RS` regex for the record at hand; it is saved in the `sep` variable for processing the *next* record.

  - Note that since the input *starts* with a record separator, the first record reported is *empty* - hence the `$0==""` pattern and associated action.
  - For all subsequent records the inital `\n` must be chopped off the separator, which is what the `substr()` call does.
- `1+gsub("\n.","")` is a little trick that effectively simply *counts* the number of non-empty lines in the record (`gsub()` returns the number of replacements made).